# What can Jay Nixon do now?

Tags: lawyer, sixth-amendment

Following the [Public Defender of Missouri assigning Governor Jay Nixon](http://www.publicdefender.mo.gov/Newsfeed/Delegation_of_Representation.PDF) to a case, what are his options?

Comment: Act as lawyer for the defendant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Some options](https://www.reddit.com/r/law/comments/4w19ti/underfunded_missouri_public_defender_does_not/):

- Act as directed
- Find a replacement
- Leave the Bar
- Claim a conflict of interest

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the options in Dawn's answer he can also claim a violation of his due process rights. He could also try to argue the government is violating his 13th amendments right to be free from involuntary servitude.

Comment: What's the down vote for?